# Difference between log(dataframe) in IPython and in execution

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, runtime-error

I have a `pandas` data frame as an attribute in Python 2.7, called `probs`. If I try to execute

`log(self.prob['AAA'])`

(where `AAA` is a valid name for one of the columns in the data frame), I get the error

```
exceptions.TypeError occurred
Message: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

but in the interactive IPython, populating `df` with the same values and executing

`log(df0['AAA'])`

produces exactly what is needed (data frame column with each value being the log() of the original data).

What is the reason for the difference and is there a way to get the IPython behavior in the regular script?

Comment: You'll need to provide the code you use to load `probe` in the interpreter and from a file. I'm guessing the difference lies there.

Comment: try to print `help(log)`, and `help(adataframe['AAA'])` or `print adataframe['AAA']` in both cases and see if there is a difference

Comment: @TomAugspurger I'm using exactly the same code to read it in from a database and reshape it -- calling the same getter/formatter functions, no other changes

Comment: @joaquin that was it, apparently IPython uses a different kind of log() function.

Comment: @joaquin please write the comment as an answer, i'll gladly accept it. But how can I get that IPython default log() function in my script?

Comment: @joaquin got it, need to use numpy log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When IPython is started with the `-pylab` parameter it loads `numpy.log` and other numpy functions by default.
It is possible that you are not using `numpy.log` in your script but maybe `math.log`, so that it fails